# How to get data from radiobuttons group by php in feedback form?

Tags: php

Please, help with this situation: I have simple feedback form with rating buttons by type "radio":

```
<form action="php/feedback.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput2" placeholder="Name and Surname)" name="q4" required>
<p>Please, rate us!</p>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  id="inlineRadio1" value="1" name="q5_1"> 1 </label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  id="inlineRadio2" value="2" name="q5_2"> 2 </label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  id="inlineRadio3" value="3" name="q5_3"> 3 </label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  id="inlineRadio4" value="4" name="q5_4"> 4 </label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  id="inlineRadio5" value="5" name="q5_5"> 5 </label>
</form>
```

And my php code:

```
<? 
$adminemail="test@test.mymail"; 
$date=date("d.m.y"); 
$time=date("H:i"); 
$backurl="http://test.mymail"; 
$q4=$_POST['q4']; 
if ($_POST['q5_1']==="1") echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_1']; 
if ($_POST['q5_2']==="2") echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_2']; 
if ($_POST['q5_3']==="3") echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_3']; 
if ($_POST['q5_4']==="4") echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_4']; 
if ($_POST['q5_5']==="5") echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_5']; 
{   
$msg=" 
Name: $q4
Rate: $q5_1 $q5_2 $q5_3 $q5_4 $q5_5
"; 
mail("$adminemail", "$date $time Feedback from $q4", "$msg" ,"Content-type:text/plain;  charset=utf-8");
print "<script language='Javascript'><!-- function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 2000); //--></script> 
<p>Redirecting....</p>";  
exit; 
}
?>
```

And data from the radio buttons do not enter the message. And I do not know how to make it work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your Radio buttons should have an equal `name` attribute (`name="q5"`)- then, when submitting it, value will be attached to that name. (I.e. `$_POST["q5"]` will either be `1,2,3,4` or `5` depending on the selected button.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to submit the data to your `php` page, either with `ajax` or a simple `input` tag with `type='submit'`, you also had numerous syntactical errors in your `php` code

```
<?php 
if(POST_['submit']){ //to make sure data was actually sent from the page
$adminemail="test@test.mymail"; 
$date=date("d.m.y"); 
$time=date("H:i"); 
$backurl="http://test.mymail"; 
$q4=$_POST['q4']; 
if ($_POST['q5_1']=="1"){ echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_1'];} 
if ($_POST['q5_2']=="2"){ echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_2'];}
if ($_POST['q5_3']=="3"){ echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_3'];}
if ($_POST['q5_4']=="4"){ echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_4'];}
if ($_POST['q5_5']=="5"){ echo $q5_1=$_POST['q5_5'];} 
 //{ not sure why this was here  
$msg=" 
Name: $q4
Rate: $q5_1 $q5_2 $q5_3 $q5_4 $q5_5
"; 
mail("$adminemail", "$date $time Feedback from $q4", "$msg" ,"Content-type:text/plain;  charset=utf-8");
print "<script language='Javascript'><!-- function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 2000); //--></script> 
<p>Redirecting....</p>";  
exit; 
//} or this
} //end of submit post
?>
```

Comment: having unrequired `{` and `}` is not a syntax error. They are not required, but it's not wrong.

Comment: Makes for organizing code better, I know it's not required. But neat code is happy code